# remove rows when values from two columns are the same combination in pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe like below.  (just an example.  My real data has millions of rows):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ZIP1': ['50069', '50069', '50704', '50704', '52403', '52403'],
              'ZIP2': ['50704', '52403', '50069', '52403', '50069', '50704'],
              'STATE': ['IA', 'IA', 'IA', 'IA', 'IA', 'IA'],
              'REGION': ['MIDWEST', 'MIDWEST', 'MIDWEST', 'MIDWEST', 'MIDWEST', 'MIDWEST'] } )
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)

    ZIP1    ZIP2    STATE   REGION
0   50069   50704   IA  MIDWEST
1   50069   52403   IA  MIDWEST
2   50704   50069   IA  MIDWEST
3   50704   52403   IA  MIDWEST
4   52403   50069   IA  MIDWEST
5   52403   50704   IA  MIDWEST
```

If two zipcodes from `ZIP1` and `ZIP2` columns are the same combination, I need to remove one row. For example,  `row 0` and `row 2`, the zipcodes are simply the same combination, but in reversed order.  I need to remove either `row 0` or `row 2`. Likewise, remove either `row 1` or `row 4`....

Does anyone know how to achieve this in pyspark? Pyspark solution is needed.  If someone can provide solutions in both pyspark and python, that is a plus. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Pandas solution

```
cols = ['ZIP1', 'ZIP2']
df[cols] = np.sort(df[cols], axis=1)
df.drop_duplicates(subset=cols)
```

###### Result

```
    ZIP1   ZIP2 STATE   REGION
0  50069  50704    IA  MIDWEST
1  50069  52403    IA  MIDWEST
3  50704  52403    IA  MIDWEST
```

### Pyspark solution

```
cols = ['ZIP1', 'ZIP2']
sdf.withColumn('arr', F.array_sort(F.array(*cols))).drop_duplicates(['arr']).drop('arr')
```

###### Result

```
| ZIP1| ZIP2|STATE| REGION|
+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|50069|50704|   IA|MIDWEST|
|50069|52403|   IA|MIDWEST|
|50704|52403|   IA|MIDWEST|
+-----+-----+-----+-------+
```

---

In both solutions the main idea is to sort the values in columns `ZIP1` and `ZIP2`, then drop the duplicates based on sorted values

Answer (score 1):

```
new = (sdf.withColumn('grouper',array_sort(array('ZIP1','ZIP2')))#Create grouper column
        .drop_duplicates(['grouper'])#Use grouper to drop duplicates
        .drop('grouper')#drop grouper column
       ).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new DF1 with zip1 and zip2 in asc order, i.e. zip1 always smaller or equal to zip2 per row.
2. Create new DF2 based on `.distinct()` from DF1.

Comment: How can this be incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way it could be done in `pandas`:

```
df = df.iloc[df[['ZIP1', 'ZIP2']].apply(set, axis=1).drop_duplicates().index]
# df.iloc[df.apply(set, axis=1).drop_duplicates().index]
# Also works if you want to include all columns~
```

Output:

```
    ZIP1   ZIP2 STATE   REGION
0  50069  50704    IA  MIDWEST
1  50069  52403    IA  MIDWEST
3  50704  52403    IA  MIDWEST
```